# Unexpected '[' - no error on localhost but there is one on server

Tags: php

```
$query_var[] = '`'.array_keys($activeFilters)[$i].'` LIKE concat(\'%\',:'.array_keys($activeFilters)[$i].',\'%\')';
```

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['

So the following line generates an error in my Xampp apache server on localhost the error isn't occurring. Also on my server there was an error also with

```
$query_var = [];
```

but I changed it to `$query_var = array();` and the error wanst appearing it was also a unexpected [

I am nearly sure it has something to do with the PHP version or something like that

Comment: Making only the first part into `$query_var = array()` is not enough, `array_keys($activeFilters)[$i]` will still throw an error – function array dereferencing is also a feature introduced with PHP 5.4

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

Comment: @Rizier123 lol i marked as that dupe then removed it, its not really a dupe of that its a php version issue

Comment: @Dagon I know: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29505827/3933332 PHP array dereferencing PHP 5.4; So it is a dupe

Comment: @Rizier123 ok fair call, i just wanted the points ;-)

Answer (score 0):

correct, its a php version issue as of php 5.4 you can use

`$query_var = [];`

http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

so your  host is running an older php version.